# Error in Inline Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, reporting, filters

I have summary report chart. which is to be displayed in visual force page.
Report is geting displayed. but when I try to add filter criteria it shows Error

> [For the filter 1: Specify a valid filterable column because 00Ng0000001eiJ6 is invalid.]

```
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00Og0000000eIkt"  
filter="[{column:'00Ng0000001eiJ6', operator:'equals', value:'{!country}'}]"  size="medium" >
</analytics:reportChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you want for the column?

if you want the field, then
You have to give the API name as **column:'(API_Name__c)'**

Comment: Yeah I used api name as well "Countries__c" It shows same error

Comment: same error as above? that means the same id coming in error?

Comment: use hideOnError="true" refer this page**https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm**

Comment: [For the filter 1: Specify a valid filterable column because Countries__c is invalid.]

Comment: If i write hideOnError="true" It doesnt show report

Comment: `<analytics:reportChart reportId="INSERT_REPORT_ID_HERE"
                       hideonerror="true"
                       filter="{column:'Account.Name', operator:'equals', value:'{!ChildObjectAPI__c.ParentObjectAPI__r.FIELDAPI__c}'}"
                       ></analytics:reportChart>`

Comment: still facing same issue

Comment: Try this if you can, **http://peterknolle.com/apex-analytics-api-and-report-chart-component/**

Answer (score 0):

I would look into coloumn countries__C to find what data type it is.Some fields may not be filterable.

Another think is check FLS of the field .If FLS is not visible this some times cause issues.

Comment: Countries__c in Picklist. when I generate report manualy filter criteria work. But when I do the same in VF page It doesnt work